# Почему ломается вёрстка в данном случае?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Разбираюсь в примере адаптивной вёрстки с w3schools. И не могу понять, почему, когда я убираю вроде необязательный кусок кода, ломается вся вёрстка.

Удаляю я `overflow: hidden;` на 29 строке. Думал, что не обязательный, потому что вроде как никакого переполнения за пределы родительского div не было.. Да и даже если бы было, боковые блоки уж точно не должны были так крупно сдвинуться вниз страницы.. Странное достаточно поведение, в общем.

Привожу код:

```css
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    body {
      font-family: Arial;
      padding: 10px;
      background: #f1f1f1;
    }
    
    /* Header/Blog Title */
    .header {
      padding: 30px;
      text-align: center;
      background: white;
    }
    
    .header h1 {
      font-size: 50px;
    }
    
    /* Style the top navigation bar */
    .topnav {
      /* WHAT??? */
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #333;
    }
    
    /* Style the topnav links */
    .topnav a {
      float: left;
      display: block;
      color: #f2f2f2;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    /* Change color on hover */
    .topnav a:hover {
      background-color: #ddd;
      color: black;
    }
    
    /* Create two unequal columns that floats next to each other */
    /* Left column */
    .leftcolumn {   
      float: left;
      width: 75%;
    }
    
    /* Right column */
    .rightcolumn {
      float: left;
      width: 25%;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      /* WHAT??? */
      padding-left: 20px;
    }
    
    /* Fake image */
    .fakeimg {
      background-color: #aaa;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 20px;
    }
    
    /* Add a card effect for articles */
    .card {
      background-color: white;
      padding: 20px;
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
    
    /* Clear floats after the columns */
    .row:after {
      content: "";
      display: table;
      clear: both;
    }
    
    /* Footer */
    .footer {
      padding: 20px;
      text-align: center;
      background: #ddd;
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
    
    /* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 800px wide, make the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
    @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
      .leftcolumn, .rightcolumn {   
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0;
      }
    }
    
    /* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 400px wide, make the navigation links stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
    @media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
      .topnav a {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
      }
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div class="header">
      <h1>My Website</h1>
      <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="topnav">
      <a href="#">Link</a>
      <a href="#">Link</a>
      <a href="#">Link</a>
      <a href="#" style="float:right">Link</a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row">
      <div class="leftcolumn">
        <div class="card">
          <h2>TITLE HEADING</h2>
          <h5>Title description, Dec 7, 2017</h5>
          <div class="fakeimg" style="height:200px;">Image</div>
          <p>Some text..</p>
          <p>Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <h2>TITLE HEADING</h2>
          <h5>Title description, Sep 2, 2017</h5>
          <div class="fakeimg" style="height:200px;">Image</div>
          <p>Some text..</p>
          <p>Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="rightcolumn">
        <div class="card">
          <h2>About Me</h2>
          <div class="fakeimg" style="height:100px;">Image</div>
          <p>Some text about me in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim..</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <h3>Popular Post</h3>
          <div class="fakeimg"><p>Image</p></div>
          <div class="fakeimg"><p>Image</p></div>
          <div class="fakeimg"><p>Image</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <h3>Follow Me</h3>
          <p>Some text..</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="footer">
      <h2>Footer</h2>
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Если вы про исчезновение последней ссылки, то уберите ей `float:right`, когда убираете `overflow:hidden`

Comment: @DaemonHK Так она не исчезает. Исчезает вообще весь навбар и заодно с собой разносит половину страницы, абсолютно ломая адаптивность и превращая две колонки в одну кривую.

Comment: @DaemonHK Когда убрал ещё и `float: right`, в целом, ничего сильно не изменилось. Навбар, как минимум, не вернулся.

Comment: Тьфу ты) в адаптивной версии смотрел. Уберите ссылкам `float:left` и поставьте `display:inline-block`

Comment: И постарайтесь верстать вообще без флоатов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вопрос сугубо образовательный, то вам стоит почитать вот [эту](https://habr.com/ru/post/48383/) статью.

Если коротко, то `overflow:hidden` выполняет роль очистки последствий свойства `float` внутри элемента к которому применён. Когда вы его отключаете, родитель получает нулевую высоту и меню как бы исчезает.

Если вопрос в исправлении ситуации и замены `overflow` иным значением, то там вариантов масса. Использовать `flexbox`, задать родителю `display: table` с шириной 100%, заменить float у ссылок на  `display:inline-block` (не забывайте учитывать боковые отступы при использовании данного свойства), использовать псевдоэлемент `:after` со стилем `clear="all"` и т.д..