# Div не выравнивается float:left

Tags: css, html

Всем привет. У меня первый сайт и я столкнулся со следующей проблемой: div "item" должен выравниваться float:left, но если я это указываю, пропадает фон блока wrapbody см картинки.
[image: Без float:left]
[image: С float:left]

Код

```css
html, body {width:100%;font-family:Tahoma;font-size:10pt;}
.main{width:930px;margin:auto;}
.left-block {float:left;width:150px;height:300px;}
.content{float:left;width:660px;}
.banner{margin:0 15px;}
.right-block{float:left;width:120px;height:300px;}
.ul_menu{margin:0;padding:0;list-style-type:none;}
.ul_menu li{background:black;border-top:2px solid white;}
.ul_menu a{color:white;padding:5px;}
.wrapbody{margin:10px 15px;background:black;color:white;}
.bodym15{width:600px;margin:10px 15px;}
.item{float:left;width:180px;height:220px;padding:25px 0 0 15px;}
.item a{font-weight:bold;}
.price a{font-weight:normal;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Интернет-магазин</title>
 <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="main">
 <div class="left-block">
  <img src="img/150.png">
  <ul class="ul_menu">
   <li><a>Категория</a></li>
   <li><a>Категория</a></li>
   <li><a>Категория</a></li>
   <li><a>Категория</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="ul_menu">
   <li><a>Бренд</a></li>
   <li><a>Бренд</a></li>
   <li><a>Бренд</a></li>
   <li><a>Бренд</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="content">
   <div class="banner">
   <img src="img/630x150.png">
   </div>
  <div class="wrapbody">
   <div class="bodym15">
   <div class="item">
    <img src="img/180.png">
    <a>Название товара</a>
    <div class="price"><a>Ценар.</a></div>
   </div>
   <div class="item">
    <img src="img/180.png">
    <a>Название товара</a>
    <div class="price"><a>Ценар.</a></div>
   </div>
   <div class="item">
    <img src="img/180.png">
    <a>Название товара</a>
    <div class="price"><a>Ценар.</a></div>
   </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="right-block">
  <p>Корзина пуста</p>
 </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: У вас тот же [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/958879/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%91%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5/958948#958948)

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что свойство float убирает элемент из привычного потока элементов в документе и в итоге он становится невидимый для других. В результате получается, что в вашем родительском элементе wrapbody отсутствует контент и его высота равна нулю и именно поэтому вы и не видите фон у этого блока. Чтобы wrapbody понимал, что в нем находятся элементы со свойством float, задайте следующие правила в CSS:

```
.wrapbody::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear:both;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает